# Split data, train model on split data, then recombine outcomes in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

So what's going on is that I have a data set that is 860k lines long and approximately 520 columns wide (the vast majority of which are boolean indicating that a word either appears or does not appear in a given body of text). I want to build a model off of this data set to predict a rating given the existence of various words using the `caret` package. However even 36gb of ram is not enough to run it all at once (obviously I'll only be training on about 600k but still). I've managed to get the model to complete with about 25k records. So this leads me to believe that my best bet is to train on 25k records at a time and then  combine the models. But I'm not sure how to do this or if this is the best approach. Does anyone have suggestions? I'm getting tired of my computer slowing to a crawl for 6 hours then erring out when it runs out of memory.

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave information on what your model structure is.  What type of model is it, using what package, etc.?

Comment: I created a boolean matrix with those dimensions and it only takes 1.7Gb to store it. Which makes me think you're using memory inefficiently... are the boolean variables stored as `logical` or `integer` (or even `numeric`)?

Comment: @MichaelChirico are you using a sparse matrix (`library(Matrix)`)? That might make it even more memory efficient.

Comment: @alex no, but sure. point is I think 36g of ram shouldn't bind for the exercise mentioned (though to be fair I've never done any deep learning, just can't imagine needing ~20x the memory)

Comment: @MichaelChirico sorry, I must not have been clear. I agree with you completely

Comment: Without knowing the answers to @Cotton.Rockwood questions it is difficult to assess where the problem lies. But first read through the caret documentation. There are default settings that add overhead to the model which you might not need. Or settings that you turned on that add overhead.

Comment: I'm using the gbm package currently. I'll do more research on Caret and gbm and report back later. Will a sparse matrix work with more than one data type? I'm currently using a data.frame. The majority of my data is stored as logical but I also have factor, integer, and POSIX data.

Comment: You might want to consider using feature hashing to represent your predictors. Also, take some of that data up-front and do feature selection with it, then fit a smaller model. Finally, consider using `xgboost` instead of `gbm` since it can [handle sparse matrices](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/R-package/demo/basic_walkthrough.R)

Comment: So two things were going on but hat tip to @topepo you got me thinking and I was able to eliminate some of my data because of how few words that I am using actually showed up in those blocks of text. Additionally somehow my garbage collection wasn't starting. After I reset it and the trigger was below my actual memory threshold, it started working. Still slow because it's a lot of data but functioning. I might just rent some time on Amazon to speed it up because they have a machine that's about 4 times as powerful as mine for 2.50 something an hour. So thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, does caret even support merging training?  What type of model are you building?  The ones I generally use have no way to merge partial training sets.  I know you already asked this, but without a positive answer to that problem, an entire branch of solution goes away.

Are there expected cross-correlations among the words, such that the presence of a certain pair yields a significantly different rating from what you get with each of the words in isolation?  If the words appear independent, then my first thought is to split the columns, not the rows, and try training batches of words in dependently.

Your description implies a matrix of an integer (short) rating, a good 400 bits, and then perhaps 100 other items -- integers?  From this, I derive a record size of a bit less than 500 bytes.  860k of those occupies less than 500Mb.  If we don't pack the booleans, it's still under 1Gb.  WOuld a better mapping -- perhaps with a slight performance penalty on unpacking each record -- fix the problem?  How about a sparse matrix?  Almost all of those booleans will be false, neh?

Do you really need over 1k lines of training per word?  Can you chop that down to a tractable size, especially if reformatting your data representation saves you most, but not all, of the space you need?